# ".resize" event don't work with "offset" together

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? it just crashes my browser and that's all...

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var p = $("#outer_wrap");
    var offset = p.offset();
    alert("left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use the `alert` function but `console.log`instead (make sure a console window is open), this works for me. This is probably caused by the handling of the `resize` event across browsers (some browsers continuously send the event as the window is resizing.

From [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/):

> Code in a resize handler should never rely on the number of times the handler is called. Depending on implementation, resize events can be sent continuously as the resizing is in progress (the typical behavior in Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers such as Safari and Chrome), or only once at the end of the resize operation (the typical behavior in some other browsers such as Opera).

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine in general, I imagine its the alerts that are causing you issues as it will be firing those events a lot.

Here's an example showing it without the alerts but outputting your results a different way, it shouldn't crash.

http://jsfiddle.net/TZfeK/

You can also see how many times that event is being fired.